# Не работает jquery код в CHROME

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
 <option id="17" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="175" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="172" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
</select> 

$('.region-listing').on('click',function () {
    $(this).text('не работает');
    console.log('РАБОТАЕТ') 
    }); console.log('123');
```

[image: chrome]
[image: firefox]

1 cкрин хром, второй мозила
код работает в firefox, но не работает в chrome, я не понимаю в чем дело.

https://jsfiddle.net/nfakx8jg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
  $(this).find(':selected').text('не работает');
  console.log('РАБОТАЕТ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
  <option id="17" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
  <option id="175" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
  <option id="172" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
  <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
  <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо, этот способ заработал.

Answer (score 0):

хром дофига правильный (или наоборот). У option нет такого ивента, как click. Соответственно он (click) хромом и не обрабатывается на option-ах

```js
$('.selectpicker').on('click', function () {
  let selected = $('.selectpicker option:selected');
  selected.text('не работает');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
 <option id="17" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="175" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="172" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
 <option id="1237" class="region-listing" value="Иркутская область">sdsdsd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: не знал про это, спасибо